# How to escape forward slash '/' in path with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

Recently, I wrote a powershell script to handle some infomation in registry. But when I access the registry path in the image by use cmdlet

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\MAPI/Attachment'
```

I got a error info:

*Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MAPI\Attachment' because it does not exist.*

I know it's because of the forward slash `/` in the path, but I want to know how can I escape it, or how can I access the path by any method.

[image]

Comment: Use the back tick. You can also just specify `-LiteralPath` instead.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I have already used the `-LiteralPath`, it didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're seeing a bug / design limitation, still present as of PowerShell 7.2: `/` is also treated as a path separator, in addition to `\ `. While this interchangeable separator use is helpful with _file-system_ paths, it causes problems in registry paths, given that `/` is a legal character in key names. See [GitHub issue #5536](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5536#issuecomment-346917545]. Escaping `/` with `\`` doesn't work; the pragmatic workaround is to enumerate the parent path's keys and filter with `Where-Object` by name. /cc @AbrahamZinala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work arround, if you really want to get the object you can use :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes' | where {$_.name -like "*MAPI/Attachment"}
```

To be more efficient as @mklement0 comment suggest :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes' | where PSChildName -eq 'MAPI/Attachment'
```

Comment: This can work, but it's a pity that it can’t be used well in scripts. My original intention was to traverse the registry.

Comment: It's why I called it a work arround. ;)

Comment: Nice, though for increased robustness II suggest `where { $_.name -like "*\MAPI/Attachment" }` (note the `\ `) or,  a bit more efficiently, `where { $_.PSChildName -eq 'MAPI/Attachment' }` (with simplified syntax: `| where PSChildName -eq 'MAPI/Attachment'`)

Comment: @JPBlanc I saw
@mklement0’s comments, maybe this is the best way, at least for the current version of powershell, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Could replace the forward slash with the unicode character:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\MAPI/Attachment'.Replace("/",[char]0x2215)
```

Comment: It seems that `[char]0x2215` is the `∕` but not the `/`, and it doesn't work after I tried

Comment: Apart from being obscure, this would only work if you used this replacement character (DIVISION SLASH, [`U+2215`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215)) in the actual key name too, not just on lookup - and doing so isn't an option with keys defined by someone else, such as in this case.